# SC2 advice for a poor multitasker

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build and fight simultaneously in Starcraft 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/how-to-build-and-fight-simultaneously-in-starcraft-2)

I'm multitasking-impaired. I do well in twitch-based and turn-based games, but the average chimp could humiliate me in the average RTS. I'd like to join some friends who are playing SC2, though, so I've learned enough from the solo game to try PvP.

Can anyone offer specific tips for a poor multitasker? For example, I know to:

- learn and use hotkeys
- group units by number so I don't have to flail around finding them
- set rally points so new units will do reasonable things initially

Other advice? Are some units or strategies more self-running than others? Does one race require less micro than the others (for example, the fewer units I need to individually direct, the better)?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/how-to-build-and-fight-simultaneously-in-starcraft-2

Comment: In addition you might find this useful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900

Comment: Thanks, great tips in those earlier questions. 

Even though 4732 has some overlap with my question, I'm still interested in whether there are specific units, races, or approaches that reduce multitasking. (Understanding that the answer might be "no" :-). 

In other words, besides tips on how to multitask better, are there races, units, or approaches require less multitasking than others?

Comment: @Andy in that case you are probably interested in this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3741

Comment: This daily from day[9] helped me a lot: http://day9tv.blip.tv/file/3732340/

Comment: Thanks, those also have good, relevant information. And on closing as a duplicate--fair enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer is somewhat subjective, but here is my take:

I personally find Zerg to demand more micro than other races. The queen requires more upkeep, and for me to use it correctly I need to remember when I actually need to Spawn Larva, on which base, need to have an exact plan of what to do with this extra larva, need to remember to spread creep all the time...

By comparison, the Terran's MULEs and Protoss' Chrono Boost are easier to use correctly (IMO).

Since these abilities (MULE/Chrono/Queen) are so essential to almost any strategy, I hardly play Zerg.

I also tend to focus on units that require less micro. With Protoss, I hardly use High Templars because they're so fragile, and if caught off guard they will simply die easily (without using their special abilities I think they don't even have an attack). I prefer Dark Templars because you can just build those and Attack-Move into your opponent's base with relative success. Also carriers are great if you can tech up, because it's easier to control relatively few units, that still do a great amount of damage.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, especially about carriers. I've been teching to air combat and having good success.

Comment: Beware that carriers get wrecked by anything with decent armour, as their damage-per-shot is low.  Battlecruisers, corruptors, +2-upgraded turrets, etc...

Also, given that ultralisks can get +5 armour, although carriers _do_ counter them, you will lose a lot of ground units / buildings in the process.

Answer (score 2):

I suggested the Daily from Day[9] before, but to summarize it a little:

**Hotkeys**

Don't click on items! If you don't know the hotkey, hover over it, read the key that is shown there, move your mouse back into the playing field and press the hotkey.

Of course this will slow you down and you will lose a few matches, but well, you never learn without losing. I personally don't like the grid hotkeys. They might help some players, but you still need to remember the position of the command. It's easier for me to remember the mnemonic hotkeys ([B]uild -> B[u]nker => [Bu]nker, [B]uild -> [B]arracks, [B]uild -> [H]atchery, [B]uild -> [N]exus, etc.)

**Grouping Units by Numbers**

What you can practice as Zerg (though you might lose matches) is to store half your zerglings in group 1, the other half in group 2. When you attack, let both attack from different angles.

For macro, as explained in the above Daily, keep your command center, hatchery or nexus in group 4 or 5 and instead of clicking the command center and clicking on the worker icon (or pressing the hotkey) remember to *always* press 4->[S]CV or 4->[S]pawn->[D]rone.

**Rally Points**

I rarely use them for something different than gathering my units near my base and sending my workers to work.

It's dangerous to use them for something else because they will execute a move command so if they encounter an enemy they will just die.

For a rush it might be nice to set the rally point into the enemy base or at least close, but as i don't rush i can't tell much about that.